# transferring pictures each 7-8 MB from NOKIA 6.1. to a laptop Win made them 5.58GB? why? how did this happen?

Tags: pictures

I am completely puzzled how this happened. I decided to transfer my phone (NOKIA 6.1) pictures to my laptop Win (an action I have successfully completed many times via the USB cable that goes with the phone), however this time my 7-8MB pictures turned to 5.58 GB each and I can no longer open them on the laptop. I tried to return them to the phone (as in the end these are its pictures), but it does not open them either. What happened? Have you some explanation? I tried various tricks to open them in word , paint and many other app I have on the laptop, but I always receive an error because of this huge 5.58GB size. How did that happen? 7MB to 5.58GB? Can I reverse the process or I have to delete 1000 pictures now?

Thank you and best regards, Mariya

Comment: maybe data corruption?

Comment: I suppose you are right, but how did it happen?

Comment: is there any going back to normal sized pictures? or I have to delete all of them now.

Comment: Try to cut one such picture after 8MB and see if you can open it.

Comment: I am trying but no online compressor wants my files - each of them 5.58 GB. I also tried in Photoshop image viewer and they say " file appears to be unsupported or damaged"....Can I somehow compress without using an online compressor? I already tried to open in Paint and cut the size as I know this is one way, but the trouble is that Paint cannot even open it. " an unknown error occurred while processing".

Comment: I meant to cut it using a file utility, not an image utility. For example, a hex editor.

Comment: That is a wonderful idea! Thank you! I am currently trying to cut and cut, but so far no success with the final result. I looked at how a normal image should look and what I notice in my corrupted images is that all meaningful letters and numbers are stacked together without any 0s in between. Therefore, even after exporting them in a separate file, they do not produce an image that displays anything.

Comment: An image wouldn't have many zero byte, but there should be some, especially at the beginning in the header. Don't you see any? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc                                                                                                                  yes, there are many rows of 0s and then we have some numbers and letters. I am trying to copy-paste some but it is always too much for the number of characters allowed and I don't see a possibility to attach a picture.

Comment: Just write out to a file the first 8MB.

Comment: @harrymc ok, I have tried but 8MB seems to be a lot considering I have to scroll through those 0s manually. If there is not an easier way to do it, I might have to give up as my fingers hurt and I am only at 356 KB. However, I was really curious if it would work as your idea seems really great! Thank you so much!

Comment: All [Hex Editors](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-hex-editor.htm) can use byte offsets. For example HxD: Use *Edit > Select block* then *File > Save selection*.

Comment: @harrymc yes, I was using this option, although in the online version of HexEditor they call it "crop these files" or "export them as a new file" etc. But it is absolutely the same as you said. However, in order to "select the block", I actually need to copy a huge amount of rows. This is what bothers me as in order for me to "select" the 8MB , I have to copy thousands of rows with 0s. I have adjusted to 64bytes per row, did zoom out to the lowest possible for me to be able to "grab" as many rows as possible, and still I scrolled and scrolled for 10min and was still at 356KB.

Comment: I assume this is not the way to do it, but I cannot find a place where to just indicate from which row to which row to crop and to to do it in 5s. It takes me a lot of time.....

Comment: Use an online product on such a file is unfeasible. Install the Windows product.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is data transfer.

Having had in the past too many issues transferring data from phones to PCs using cables (the most important is the time to transfer), long time ago I decided to always keep pictures and files in the SD memory slot that almost every decent phone has.

Once every 3 to 6 months I extract the SD from the phone and read the SD card directly using my PC.

There are various very good readers, the best ones actually use USB 3 and read/write SD, MicroSD, etc.

This is much faster and less prone to errors.

Comment: Thank you, Andrea! I also try to transfer every now and then and unluckily this time sth as bizarre as this happened. Do you think I can reverse the process or I lost the pictures for good?

Comment: What I'd try: 1) make a backup copy of one picture 2) Try to reverse using only that one 3) See what happens. I suspect the 5.58 GB are corrupted, but only some experiments on one of them can help you understand what happened.

Comment: yes, I actually did that yesterday while taking many,many desperate moves, but as you guessed it didn't work.